# how to keep "Received" header on only content_filter?

Tags: postfix

I have registered content_filter in the submission of master.cf.

But I can't find the "Received" header in the content filter due to the settings below.
I need to get "authenticated user" from "Received" from the content filter.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/78163/when-sending-email-with-postfix-how-can-i-hide-the-sender-s-ip-and-username-in

How can I remove the Received header from outgoing mail, but get it from the content filter?

master.cf:

```
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o cleanup_service_name=subcleanup
  -o content_filter=cfilter:127.0.0.1:10025

subcleanup unix n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
  -o header_checks=regexp:/etc/postfix/submission_header_checks

cfilter unix   y     y       n       -       0       smtp
  -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
  -o disable_mime_output_conversion=yes
  -o smtp_generic_maps=
  -o smtp_use_tls=no
  -o smtp_tls_security_level=none


127.0.0.1:10026 inet  n       -       n       -       10      smtpd
  -o content_filter=
  -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_header_body_checks,no_milters
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
  # Postfix 2.10 and later: specify empty smtpd_relay_restrictions.
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
  -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=127.0.0.0/8
```

I tried setting cleanup_service_name in 127.0.0.1:10026.
But in this case, the Received header is not cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the no_header_body_checks from receive_override_options so it works as desired.